# Edit and Compile AOSP Core/System Apps in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, settings, system, android-source

I've been banging my head off my keyboard all day trying to figure out how to import one of the core/system apps in the AOSP into Eclipse to edit/debug it (in this specific case, the Settings app in Android 4.0.4).

I've followed numerous guides on the subject, including this one [here](http://stoned-android.blogspot.com/2012/01/debug-and-modify-android-core-app-like.html) which got me VERY close, but the code is still returning 167 errors.

Anyone have any experience or insight with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post what errors are returned by eclipse. Otherwise, it is hard to predict )

Comment: When you are planning to use eclipse/Intellij Idea for AOSP code, you can only edit/view the code. I don't think you can build from eclipse and use the apk. Please check my answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582112/aosp-and-intellij-idea/19073832#19073832) on how to configure eclipse/Intellij to edit AOSP code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have done it. Use eclipse to edit/browse/debug platform code using an eclipse project. To build the platform, I use terminal and build the whole image or build specific folder (i.e. Using mm helper).

To create eclipse project for AOSP sources, please check [Using Eclipse to edit/browse AOSP](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html).