# AOSP and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, android-source

Has anyone tried to work with AOSP using IntelliJ IDEA? I see in Android sources a specific folder (development/ide/intellij) but I cannot find any information how to use it in case of Android development (for Eclipse the information can be found here: http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) Can anyone provide similar instructions how to start developing Android in IDEA?

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in  2020?  The answers below aren't correct any more.

Comment: @JamesMoore you should provide more details what doesn't work for you, and maybe submit an issue to AOSP bug tracker, see https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs

Answer (score 17):

Also a good reading here: https://shuhaowu.com/blog/setting_up_intellij_with_aosp_development.html

If you get

> Couldn't find idegen.jar. Please run make first.

You'll need to generate it first:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
cd development/tools/idegen
mm
croot
development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
```

Be prepared that AOSP files indexing in IJ takes long time (more than 1 hour on my notebook with an SSD on board), a reason to use Eclipse, as I believe it doesn't need to build indexes so loads AOSP code much faster.

It's worth reducing android.iml file with removing AOSP parts you are not interested in. You can add them to `development/tools/idegen/excluded-paths` via a regular expression pattern, see **README** file there.

I added following lines to `excluded-paths`:

```
^cts
^developers
^development
^external
.*/tests/.*
^sdk
```

so my `android.iml` got quite moderate size and loads in about 1-2 minutes instead.

idegen has also `intellij-gen.sh` which can generate IJ project for given module.

As mentioned in the article above, you can tweak IJ to work faster (add more RAM, etc). Here goes my idea64.vmoptions just in case:

```
-server
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024M
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:-TraceClassUnloading
-XX:+TieredCompilation
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

You can google idea.vmoptions optimization, there are some posts about it (and where I took my IJ config from)

Comment: It Works.Tested it with android-5 using android studio.

Comment: It Works, but if "out" directory isn't default you must change in "development/tools/idegen/idengen.sth" the line 7. "idegenjar=`find **out** -name idegen.jar -follow | grep -v intermediates`" for your out directory

Comment: Works perfectly, verified with RK3399 source code. Should be the accepted answer. I had tried @Jacob Abraham's answer below but without much luck, perhaps it is due to my codebase being a different "flavour" than stock AOSP from the googlesource repos.

Answer (score 7):

From AOSP root folder,

1) First build your target. That will generate whatever java files that need to be generated during aosp build.
2) Create a shadow dir of aosp dir using lndir.
Assuming your aosp dir is ~john/work/aosp/ics.
Then create ~/john/work/aosp/icsshadow

Cd to icsshadow and invoke "lndir ../ics". That will create symlinks to everything under ics.

3) Now you use icsshadow for all the stuff your IDE needs/generates. If you use ics folder, the aosp build some times fails if the IDE generates any build artifacts.

4) cd to icsshadow directory.
Invoke development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh

Wait until it is done.

5) If you want to use IntelliJ, open android.ipr from icsshadow folder. If you want to use Eclipse, Please check [Using Eclipse to edit/browse AOSP code](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html).

Comment: Mac OS X no longer has lndir, http://superuser.com/questions/171629/copy-directory-structure-without-copying-files-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2):

Official instructions can be found by going to `development/tools/idegen` path and checking the `README` file. It's a good idea to read it yourself. This is the content for IntelliJ:

> If you're using IntelliJ...
>
> If this is your first time using IDEGen...
>
> ```
>   IDEA needs a lot of memory. Add "-Xms748m -Xmx748m" to your VM options
>   in "IDEA_HOME/bin/idea.vmoptions" on Linux or
>   "IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/Info.plist" on OS X.
>
>   Create a JDK configuration named "1.6 (No Libraries)" by adding a new
>   JDK like you normally would and then removing all of the jar entries
>   under the "Classpath" tab. This will ensure that you only get access to
>   Android's core libraries and not those from your desktop VM.
> ```
>
> From the project's root directory...
>
> ```
>    Repeat these steps after each sync...
>
>   1) make (to produce generated .java source)
>   2) development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
>   3) Open android.ipr in IntelliJ. If you already have the project open,
>      hit the sync button in IntelliJ, and it will automatically detect the
>      updated configuration.
>
>   If you get unexpected compilation errors from IntelliJ, try running
>   "Build -> Rebuild Project". Sometimes IntelliJ gets confused after the
>   project changes significantly.
> ```

The following error message might pop up when following the instructions.

> Couldn't find idegen.jar. Please run make first.

You can fix the error message by reading here: https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/860?ncr=1

Comment: The README hasn't been updated, unfortunately, and this isn't correct any more - you don't run make to build at the top level, and development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh now just gives an error.

Answer (score 2):

Run the below command from the Android source root directory.

```
make idegen -j4 && development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
```

Then launch IntelliJ idea, and select the .ipr file generated. Then on the next screen select the .ipr based project property.

Works for me and better than using the android studio, because there is an annoying background scan all the time with the android studio.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 use [AIDEGen](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/asuite/+/refs/heads/master/aidegen/README.md):

## AIDEGen

AIDEGen aims to automate the project setup process for developers to work on
Java or C/C++project in popular IDE environment. Developers no longer need to manually
configure an IntelliJ project, such as all the project dependencies. It's a
**command line tool** that offers the following features:

- Configure Android Studio or IntelliJ project files with the relevant module
  dependencies resolved.
- Launch IDE for a specified sub-project or build target, i.e. frameworks/base
  or Settings.
- Launch IDE for specified folder(s) which contains build targets, i.e. cts.
- Auto configure JDK and Android coding style for IntelliJ.

### 1. Prerequisites:

- IDE installation, choose one of prefer IDE, including Android Studio,
  IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, CLion and VS Code.
- Setup Android development environment.

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh && lunch <TARGET>
```

### 2. Basic Usage:

#### Example 1: Launch IDE with module name

Example to generate and launch IntelliJ project for framework and Settings:

```
$ aidegen Settings framework
```

#### Example 2: Launch IDE with module path

Example to generate and launch IntelliJ project for framework and Settings:

```
$ aidegen packages/apps/Settings frameworks/base
```

#### Example 3: Launch IDE with build skipped

Example to generate and launch IntelliJ project for framework and Settings and
skip build time:

```
$ aidegen Settings framework -s
```

#### Example 4: Launch IDE with native module

Example to generate and launch CLion project:

```
$ aidegen <module> -i c
```

The native projects will be launched in CLion and you have to select,
**Tools > CMake > Change Project Root**
Change project root to the source directory: the relative path which is the directory shown in CLion’s project view. For example, if frameworks/base/media is your project, please change project root directly to frameworks/base/media.

### 3. Optional arguments:

Developers can also use the following optional arguments with AIDEGen commands.

| Option | Long option | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `-d` | `--depth` | The depth of module referenced by source. |
| `-i` | `--ide` | Launch IDE type, j=IntelliJ s=Android Studio e=Eclipse c=CLion v=VS Code |
| `-p` | `--ide-path` | Specify user's IDE installed path. |
| `-n` | `--no_launch` | Do not launch IDE. |
| `-r` | `--config-reset` | Reset all AIDEGen's saved configurations. |
| `-s` | `--skip-build` | Skip building jars or modules. |
| `-v` | `--verbose` | Displays DEBUG level logging. |
| `-a` | `--android-tree` | Generate whole Android source tree project file for IDE. |
| `-e` | `--exclude-paths` | Exclude the directories in IDE. |
| `-l` | `--language` | Launch IDE with a specific language,j=java c=C/C++ r=Rust |
| `-h` | `--help` | Shows help message and exits. |

### 4. Troubleshooting tips:

If you get an error like: "Dependent modules dictionary is empty." or other errors, try a make
clean.

### 5. FAQ:

Q1. If I already have an IDE project file, and I run command AIDEGen to generate
the same project file again, what'll happen?

A1: The former IDEA project file will be overwritten by the newly generated one
from the aidegen command.

Q2: When do I need to re-run AIDEGen?

A2: Re-run AIDEGen after repo sync.

### 6. Hint:

1. In IntelliJ, uses [File] > [Invalidate Caches / Restart...] to force
   project panel updated when your IDE didn't sync.
2. If you run aidegen on a remote desktop, make sure there is no IntelliJ
   running in a different desktop session.

### 6. Feedback:

If you have any questions or feedback, contact aidegen_tnn@google.com.

If you have any bugs or feature requests email them to buganizer-system+429701@google.com.

Comment: What Android version have you tried this on? Can this also be supported on Android 10?

Comment: Tried on Android 13. Not sure about 10, 11 and 12.

Answer (score 1):

**Google has introduced IDE for AOSP platform development.**

[ASFP](https://developer.android.com/studio/platform)

With ASFP you can edit both native(C++) and apps source easily!.

Comment: Is it possible to preview layout xmls? I just discovered this tool but it seems not possible to easily edit and preview layouts